# How to enable second SIM slot in ALIX6F2 and how to switch 3G to it from the 1st one?

Tags: debian, modem, mobile, gpio

I am trying to enable the SIM slot under the RF card but with no success whatsoever. I'm using Voyage 0.8 (a stripped off Debian distribution) as an operating system. A bit of searching landed me to the following steps:

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/GPIO1/direction
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/GPIO1/value
```

But when I do `echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/export`, it says `invalid argument`.

Also I cannot find anything under `/sys/class/gpio` except export and unexport. I learnt that there should be something like `GPIO1`, etc.

I have the feeling that the driver itself in not installed or may need to be reconfigured. Please tell me from where to get the GPIO driver?

Since ALIX6F2 lacks a buzzer, I unloaded the `pcspkr` module too, but with no success.